# Reading from one column and writing to another according to data

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

How I can read data in one column (column A) and based on the data in the cells (which are strings) write to column B in the same row?

For example: read the value in cell A1 (e.g. "Keyboards") and based on the value "Dell, Targus, Sony, etc" into cell B1. All in an array using columns A and B. Using the cells from .end(xlUp) to cell A1 and B1.

Optimization for speed is not all that important.

Comment: I have tried a lot of the other suggestions from similar questions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this helps get you started. Imagine I have:

```
    A              B
1   Keyboards      //result = "Dell"
2   Monitors       //result = "Sony"
3   Speakers       //results = "Targus"
```

The following code detects how many cells in column A and then loops over them to add information into column B.

```
Sub FillColumnB()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cl In rng
        If cl = "Keyboards" Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Dell"
        ElseIf cl = "Monitors" Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Sony"
        ElseIf cl = "Speakers" Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Targus"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just need to adjust the offset to the correct column which is like "J" or something in my worksheet.